# What is the most efficient way to get an answer on Ask Ubuntu about a very technical question?

Tags: discussion

I like this site, but my questions do not get answered. I believe it is because they are too technical or maybe not many people have had the problem. I wanted to know if there is any way (or place) to ask those questions to get an answer. Or what am I doing wrong in my questions. Thank you.

PS: I would have posted this in meta, but since my last question was downvoted so hard, I don't have enough reputation anymore.

Comment: Delete your downvoted question. You'll get back some rep.

Comment: I did, but the rep stayed the same. Does it take some time?

Comment: May be we are not as smart as you. If no one knows the answers to your technical questions, nobody will answer. It is as simple as that. If you want to get answers read the [Help](https://askubuntu.com/help) and figure out how best to ask questions in this site. Here is a hint: This is not the site to post questions as jokes.

Comment: Maybe things have changed from when I remember deleting your downvoted contributions got back the lost rep.

Comment: See the How to Ask page: https://meta.askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please provide one or mores examples of such questions? I can only see one question of yours without an answer and it's relatively recent and looks to be related to specific hardware, both of which make answers less likely.

Comment: @DKBose That won't necessarily restore their reputation, and is just as harmful to their ability to post questions as tones of downvotes would do.  (if a substantial percentage of posts are horridly downvoted or deleted or flagged for mod attention it runs the risk of an automated question asking restriction)

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tips:

- Work hard to summarise and narrow down the question to just the essential part.  Cut out any part of the question that doesn't contribute.  Make sure the first paragraph of the question is short and describes the exact problem as concisely as possible, and use the paragraphs underneath just to give additional information.
- Make sure you say what you are trying to achieve, as it provides context.
- Choose appropriate tags.  People with specific domain knowledge follow tags related to that knowledge.
- Consider whether another site on the StackExchange network may be more appropriate.  While your question may be about Ubuntu, if you are doing programming it may reach a more technical audience at StackOverflow.  If you're setting up a network server it may reach a more technical audience at ServerFault.  And if it's a question that may apply to Linux in general, it may reach a more technical audience at Unix&Linux StackExchange.

Comment: Thank you very much!